# Why can't I just use GroupBy for grouped LongListSelector ItemsSource

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone, longlistselector

There is a [popular example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for making a `LongListSelector` with groups. However this seems overly complex and I don't understand why just using `GroupBy` doesn't work. Given:

```
    List<string> l = new List<string>();
    l.Add("alan");
    l.Add("albert");
    l.Add("bert");
    l.Add("bill");
```

The following gives me a list as expected:

```
    LongListSelector1.ItemsSource = l;
```

However after enabling grouping on the list the following just shows me the group headers:

```
    LongListSelector1.ItemsSource = l.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, 1)).ToList();
```

I don't understand why. The `LongListSelector` has access to the `Key` and the elements of the group apparently in the same way that it does in the example linked above.